# getting a "-317629566" whenever i am executing the code

Tags: c

I am using dev++ for c programming and i have made on simple program of add,subtract,multi And div. there is no error in my code but i am getting a different type of 9 digit (`-317629566`) of message along with output in my output screen.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
    int a, b;
    char op;

    printf("select a operator(+, -, *, /) :: ");
    scanf("%c", &op);
    printf("enter first number : ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter second number : ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
            printf("addition : %d%d", a + b);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("subtraction : %d%d", a - b);
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("multiplication : %d%d", a *b);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("divison : %d%d", a / b);
            break;
        default:
            printf("not a operator");
    }
    getch();
}
```

This is the output i am getting after executing the code.

```
select a operator( + , - , * , / ) :: +
enter first number : 12
enter second number : 13
addition : 25-317629566
```

why i am getting this `-317629566` result.

Comment: `printf("addition : %d%d", a + b);` is incorrect, it expects 2 values and you only provide one. Drop one *%d*: `printf("addition: %d\n", a + b);`

Comment: @CristiFati you given the answer, by curiosity why did you used a remark rather than an answer ? I am surprised because without an answer when we look at the list of questions we cannot know the problem was solved, so lot of people will come on that question for nothing

Comment: If you want people to write in answers rather than in comments, then stop people from voting down answers when they don't like the question.

Comment: @bruno: I spotted one problem (they may be others). Also I thought that there should be many duplicate questions on this topic. After a quick search I didn't find any.one

Comment: @CristiFati thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome! Did you read my answer?

Comment: @CristiFati yes i did. i read your answer and it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("addition : %d%d", a + b);
```

You are asking `printf` to print **two** integers, but you are only passing one. This causes **undefined behavior**. In this case, it's just printing an arbitrary value, but potentially worse things could happen.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in my comment, all the 4 *printf* statements (inside the *switch* block) are wrong.

According to [[CPPReference]: std::printf, std::fprintf, std::sprintf, std::snprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) (**emphasis** is mine):

> - ***...*** - arguments specifying data to print. If any argument after [default conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions) is not the type expected by the corresponding conversion specifier, **or if there are fewer arguments than required by format, the behavior is undefined**. If there are more arguments than required by format, the extraneous arguments are evaluated and ignored

Let's take the 1<sup>st</sup> (`printf("addition : %d%d", a + b);`) as an example:

- Your string format (*printf*'s 1<sup>st</sup> argument) contains **2 *%d*** (signed integer in decimal) conversion specifiers, meaning that *printf* expects ***2*** integer values after it
- `a + b` produces only ***1*** integer value, and you fall into the **Undefined Behavior** branch. In this case, *printf* outputs garbage data (from some "random" memory address), but bear in mind that there might be cases when the program could crash

In order to fix the issues:

- Make sure that the conversion specifiers number matches the arguments number (also pay attention to their type) that follow the format: `printf("addition : %d", a + b);`
- To take things further, in order to have nicely formatted output, add a "*\n*" (*LF*, *0x0A*, *EOLN*) character at the end of the format string: when such a character is encountered, it's not displayed on screen, but the cursor jumps at the beginning of the next line: `printf("Addition: %d\n", a + b);`
- To take things even further, you can also print the numbers that yielded this result: `printf("Addition: %d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a + b);` (***3*** *%d*s, 3 integers after the format specifier)

As a final note (not related to the question itself), you might want to avoid division when *b* is 0.